# Samba smb file transfer extremely slow

Tags: network, backup, smb

So, as I don't have a SATA - USB 3 adaptor in hand right now, I decided to backup a Windows disk from the PC thought ethernet 100Mb/s (~12KB/s) so I don't have to disassemble the PC. I'd boot with a live Linux Mint 20 DVD (that's a nice tool) and get the entire Users folder. I did locate my Macbook Pro (with Big Sur 11.6.1) and my internal backup disk easily. Just drag and drop the folder and we are on - can be better?

It started to copy with speed near 500KB/s and before a go to sleep it was 320KB/s - tuck me all day and didn't end. I'd have a look on the Internet to see about samba file transfer these days. People are using but they are discussing about MB/s not KB/s! Thought I am far from the usual average speed.

Now, I think samba is still being used and improve this speed might be a good idea, I might need it again. So, how can I fix my connection to get a reasonable file transfer speed?

You think I should forgot samba? What's the alternatives for Linux / Windows speed (specially Linux because copy with Windows sucks!)

Edit: corrected the measurement of the Ethernet in Mbps. But the main question remains.

Comment: ethernet speeds are measured in mega*bits* not megabytes. 100Base-T is 100Mb/s, not 100MB/s ie about 1/5 the speed of USB2. 500kb/s transfer is a reasonable expectation for large files, but small files will slow that down. Your only real way to speed it all up would be to get gigabit ethernet 1000Base-T

Comment: Ok, I have corrected the B to b. But still 100Mbps will be about 12,5MB/s. Even not using all this bandwidth, I don't think half MB/s is reasonable expectation. I used this same ethernet to install Windows remotely, and it was fast. An Internet download can't be faster than LAN file transfer, something is wrong.